# How to Update decimal data in db with psql from the bash script

Tags: regex, postgresql, bash, sed

1. I have a table with numeric type data: numeric(9,6).
2. I want to change this data (get rid of trailing zeros) in the bash script and update it in the db.

But it looks like after manipulations in bash data should be converted to decimal again.

My .sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PSQL="psql -X --username=****** --dbname=periodic_table --tuples-only -c";

echo -e "\n~~~~~ Remove trailing zeros & update db ~~~~~\n"

# get atomic_mass
ELEMENTS=$($PSQL "SELECT atomic_number, atomic_mass FROM properties")
echo "$ELEMENTS" | while read ATOMIC_NUMBER BAR ATOMIC_MASS
do
  #echo "$ATOMIC_NUMBER | $ATOMIC_MASS"
  # remove trailing zeros
  ATOMIC_MASS_CLEAN=$(echo $ATOMIC_MASS | sed -e "s/0*\s*$//" | sed -e "s/\.$//")
  echo "$ATOMIC_NUMBER | $ATOMIC_MASS | $ATOMIC_MASS_CLEAN"
  # Update db
  UPDATE_DB=$($PSQL "UPDATE properties SET atomic_mass = $ATOMIC_MASS_CLEAN WHERE atomic_mass = $ATOMIC_MASS")
  echo $UPDATE_DB
done
```

Result

```
$ ./remove_trailing_zeros.sh 

~~~~~ Remove trailing zeros & update db ~~~~~

3 | 6.940000 | 6.94
UPDATE 1
4 | 9.012200 | 9.0122
UPDATE 1
1 | 1.008000 | 1.008
UPDATE 1
2 | 4.002600 | 4.0026
UPDATE 1
6 | 12.011000 | 12.011
UPDATE 1
7 | 14.007000 | 14.007
UPDATE 1
8 | 15.999000 | 15.999
UPDATE 1
5 | 10.810000 | 10.81
UPDATE 1
1000 | 1.000000 | 1
UPDATE 1
```

But it looks like $ATOMIC_MASS_CLEAN can't be simply converted to Numeric data :(
The script is running without errors but nothing happens in the db. Everything works fine with INT data and VARCHAR but not with Numeric.
Help to fix it, please.

Comment: please update the question with sample input and expected output (ie, contents of the 3 variables `ELEMENT`, `ELEMENT_CLEAN` and `UPDATE_DB`

Comment: also, please show the (wrong) actual and (correct) expected results for the database record(s)

Comment: If you mean that the trailing zeros are still shown in the database after the update then that is expected and is determined by the precision and scale settings for the field.

Comment: To add to my previous comment: 1) What is the issue with trailing zeros? 2) If you want to get rid of them that is going to have to be done on presentation to the user. Either by the doing something like `select  trim_scale(999.1235000::numeric(9,6)); 999.1235` , using  `to_char()` from here [Data formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) or using client side formatting. FYI, `trim_scale()` is only available in Postgres 13+.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver This is an educational project whose task is to eliminate trailing zeros in the database. I know how to do it with trim but it's not the case :( 
Can I get rid of these trailing zeros using only psql without bash scripting?

Comment: @markp-fuso I shared the full .sh script and bash output. You can see the expected result in the #3 column. But it's not appearing in the table.

Comment: as Adrian has pointed out, the database is going to store 6 digits of accuracy; you cannot 'get rid of' trailing 0's in the actual database; to 'get rid of' the trailing 0's is strictly an aspect of how the data is displayed by the front-end application (whether that's a GUI, a shell script, etc)

Comment: also, does your `UPDATE` report on how many rows are affected? something like `update table set column = 123.456 where column = 123.456000` (and assuming there's a single matching row) *will* update the row but the before/after values will be the same .... `123.456000` (ie, `123.456 == 123.456000`)

Comment: @markp-fuso understood, so no matter what I send from bash it will be shown with zeros. But then how to interpret the task definition:
"You should remove all the trailing zeros after the decimals from each row of the atomic_mass column. You may need to adjust a data type to DECIMAL for this." 
Is it about changing the table column type to DECIMAL?

Comment: depends on what is meant by *`remove all the trailing zeros`* ...  modifying the datatype of the database field would only 'work' if you knew all values (current and future) have 3 trailing zeros; consider what happens if you change the datatype to `numeric(6,3)` and you store the value `123` in the column ... it will *still* have 3 trailing zeros (`123.000`); also, keep in miind that modifying a database datatype (eg, 'remove' 3 trailing zeros) is not a typical operation (eg, what if the original design was to handle 6 digits of accuracy?) ....

Comment: my *guess* is that *`remove all the trailing zeros`* is meant as a requirement for *displaying* the data; ultimately you'll need to get (additional) input from the person who came up with the requirement to *`remove all the trailing zeros`*; for modifying what's displayed you could apply some sort of 'trim' operation (see Adrian's eaelier comment) or you could convert the *presentation* datatype to `numeric(6,3)` (though keep in mind for a database value `123.456789` you would lose some accuracy when converting to `123.457`)

Comment: just to emphasize ... modifying a database structure (eg, changing a column's datatype) just to facilitate a change in how data is *displayed* is not something that's done in the real (database) world; modifying how data is *displayed* is something left to the front-end application to handle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so much an answer as a demonstration

```
create table numeric_test(num_fld numeric, num6_fld numeric(9,6));

insert into numeric_test values (2, 2), (2.100, 2.100), (2.000, 2.000);

 select * from numeric_test ;
 num_fld | num6_fld 
---------+----------
       2 | 2.000000
   2.100 | 2.100000
   2.000 | 2.000000
```

When you create a `numeric` field with an explicit `scale`, the 6, then you will get trailing zeros out to that scale. Without an  explicit scale then the trailing zeros entered will be preserved.

Comment: you right! It was about the numeric vs numeric(9, 6) difference. I did:
`ALTER TABLE properties ALTER COLUMN atomic_mass TYPE NUMERIC;`
and everything works fine now. I get rid of trailing zeros. Thank you all a lot.

Comment: Note: that if you enter values into a `numeric()` column that have trailing zeros those zeros will be preserved. This is really something that should be done when sending the values to the client or on the client end.